# convergence of a sum fails with root test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So I was trying to find the values of $p>0$ such that the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{p}{n}\right)^n $$

converges. I tried to use the root test but the limit of that equals $1$ so the root test is inconclusive. How else would I do this question though? I can't use the integral test or the limit comparison test. The ratio test also fails.

Comment: From Bernoulli's Inequality, $\left(1-\frac pn\right)^n\ge 1-p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails to converge as the $n$th terms don't tend to $0$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{p}{n}\right)^n = e^{-p}$$

Comment: Yes of course. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: what is

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{p}{n} \right)^n ? $$

Comment: Yes I completely forgot about the definition of e. Thanks!